# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to interpret the update count in command completion tag

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

Original Error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to interpret the update count in command completion tag

I have a Redshift temp table that I transform and insert into another table.  The row count is in the billions and therefore overflows Java's `int` type.  When calling `Statement.execute()`, the JDBC driver attempts to parse the number of rows inserted and throws a `NumberFormatException`.

How can I use JDBC to execute a query that will insert billions of rows without the JDBC driver throwing an exception?

Comment: Offending code in the JDBC driver:  https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/REL8_4_702/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java#L2119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in the 9.x series of the driver.  I was using the 8.x series as per Amazon's recommendation.  Here's where the code was corrected to be able to handle longer counts:  https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/REL9_3_1102/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java#L2233

I'll leave this question open for a bit in case the 9.x driver doesn't work well with Redshift or if someone has a better answer.

edit:  This is not fixed in the whole 9.x series.  It appears that it is fixed in the version linked above.